# SQL Server dm_exec_input_buffer Problem with linq dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql, stored-procedures, profiler

I'm logging my SQL Server 2017 stored procedure parameters.

I use this code:

```
 select event_info 
 from sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(@@spid, current_request_id())
```

Inside my procedure to list parameters and everything is ok (I can see my parameters and values that are passed to).

The problem is when application sends request, there is nothing in `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer`

but

```
"@FromDate=@FromDate = @p1,@ToDate=@ToDate = @p2"
```

and there is no value! My stored procedure is called from application using linq.
That in profiler shows something like:

```
declare @p13 int
set @p13=0
declare @p14 nvarchar(4000)
set @p14=N''
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[SP_spname_Search]  @FromDate = @p1, @ToDate = @p2,@RETURN_VALUE int output',@p1='2020-01-01',@p2=NULL,@RETURN_VALUE=@p13 output
select @p13, @p14
```

I run this in SSMS, I get result in `dm_exec_input_buffer`. The application sends this and there is no result.

Could you please help me?

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefix is reserved by Microsoft for **S**pecial **P**rocedures. It should not be used for User objects, and doing so comes with a performance cost and can result in your procedure simply not working one day in the future.

Comment: Also, the `RETURN` value isn't an `OUTPUT` parameter. You're assigning the value of `@RETURN_VALUE` twice; once from an `OUTPUT`  **parameter**, another from the `RETURN` value.

Comment: @larno Thanks for attention.but this is an example I changed to ask here. in main sp these are ok

Comment: What is "ok" assigning the value in two places? Using the prefix? Neither is the case.

Comment: Incidentally, what you see in the profiler is not the actual code that is sent. It is just a representation of what the TDS conversation would look like if you were running it as a script

Answer (score 1):

The "input buffer" has data about the request that the client sent, but only contains parameter values if the client sent a batch containing local variables.  If the client sent an RPC request, you won't be able to see the parameter values that way.  You can see them in Trace or Extended events, but there's no DMV that displays them.